# email posting in formatted manner

Tags: php, email

I am having one dynamic form which collects the mobile data and sends to email through  php code. . The PHP code is given below.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
//Need to submit the form.
exit;
       }
$sl = $_POST['sl'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$place= $_POST['place'];
$mob = $_POST['mob'];

$email_body = 
"NAME         PLACE        MOBILE \n".
“===========================\n\n”;
$email_body .= 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sl); $i++) {
$i=  $i+1;
"(" . $sl[$i] . ") "  . $name[$i] .  "    "  . $place .  “    “ . $mob . “  “ ;\n";
}

$email_from = 'xxxt@xyz.com';
$email_subject = "Phone details";
$to = "yyy@xyz.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```

The above code sends the mobile details in following manner:

```
SL   NAME           PLACE   MOBILE
(1)Jhon   Newyork 6765464564
(2)Robert steevejobs  wshinton 6767565
(3)Madam levies satllen forthe  Canada 454645
```

Whereas I need the mail in following format.

```
SL   NAME                          PLACE        MOBILE
(1)  Jhon                          Newyork      6765464564
(2)  Robert steevejobs             wshinton     6767565
(3)  Madam levies satllen forthe   Canada       454645
```

Can any body help me in this please?

Answer (score 1):

You could display a html table in your email body :

```
$body = '<table>';
$body .= '<thead><th>Column 1 title</th><th>Column 2 title</th></thead>';
$body .= '<tbody>';
$body .= '<tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</tr>';
$body .= '</tbody>';
$body .= '</table>';
```

And don't forget to specify in your headers that you want to display html :

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: the td widths differs for each (ie SL, NAME, PLACE, MOBILE).  Instead of table, isl span class better?

Comment: the table width will adapt itself to the data. So no, a table is a much better option than span with style. Moreover, you can not guess the ideal width for your spans since the data can be completely different from one user to another

Answer (score 0):

Use `<table>`

```
$email_body = "<table>";
$email_body .= "<tr>";
$email_body .= "<td>SL</td>";
$email_body .= "<td>NAME</td>";
$email_body .= "<td>PLACE</td>";
$email_body .= "<td>MOBILE</td>";
$email_body .= "</tr>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($sl); $i++) {
    $i=  $i+1;
    $email_body .= "<tr>";
    $email_body .= "<td>(" . $sl[$i] . ")</td> ";
    $email_body .= "<td>". $name[$i] .  "</td>";
    $email_body .= "<td>". $place . "</td>";
    $email_body .= "<td>".  $mob . "</td>";
    $email_body .= "</tr>";
}
$email_body .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Can <span class> be used with css, instead of table

Comment: yes but table will give you accurate spacing so it will be better.

Comment: <td> width adjust automatically for all same in table so it will better to use. Give you same desire output which you added in above image. @guruje

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_body = '<table>';
$email_body .= '<thead><th>SL</th><th>NAME</th><th>PLACE</th><th>MOBILE</th></thead>';
$email_body .= '<tbody>';
$email_body .= '<tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td><td>Col 4</td></tr>';
$email_body .= '</tbody>';
$email_body .= '</table>';


add header also - 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```